# Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<String> to ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections

I faced with "Type mismatch" problem during the compilation of the code. Actually I do not know why List cannot be converted to the ArrayList. I used java.util.Collections.singletonList and wanted to convert to the List.

I have tried to cast the expression to the ArrayList but it cannot be cast.

```
public class AlphabeticShifts  {

    public static ArrayList<String> DoAlphapeticShifts(ArrayList<String> sentences) {
        Collections.sort(sentences, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        return sentences;
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args){
        DoAlphapeticShifts(java.util.Collections.singletonList("Array"));
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The method DoAlphapeticShifts(ArrayList<String>) in the type AlphabeticShifts is not applicable for the arguments (List<String>)
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<String> to ArrayList<String>

    at AlphabeticShifts.main(AlphabeticShifts.java:15)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ArrayList` is a subclass of the interface `List`. Because of this we can convert an `ArrayList` into a `List`, because we know that `ArrayList` implements all of `List`'s methods (of course, it's an interface)

But if we try to convert from `List` to `ArrayList`, `List` is just an interface, so we can't downgrade since we don't know if that list is a subclass of `ArrayList` at all.

Essentially, `ArrayList` is a specific type of a `List`. So since we're not sure if that `List` is definitely `ArrayList`, the compiler can't tell for sure if that's a valid cast.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort and return a general list of strings, preserving the type of the parameter, change the method signature to:

```
public static <L extends List<String>> L DoAlphapeticShifts(L sentences) {
```